# capture a element with event double click vb.net devexpress

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

```
Private Sub dtgpersonal_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtgpersonal.DoubleClick
    DNIValue = griddtgpersonal.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("DNI").Value
    DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
End Sub
```

I need to capture the data of a form and pass it to another form in a textbox , I just want to capture the DNI

[image]

Comment: `the Row tells me that is not a member of DevExpress` - what does it mean?

Comment: this is the error 'rows is not a member of devExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView'

Answer (score 0):

[GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowCellValuetopic) Method:

```
DNIValue = griddtgpersonal.GetRowCellValue(e.RowIndex, "DNI");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no properties in `GridView` like `Rows` property. You need to use [`ColumnView.GetFocusedRowCellValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetFocusedRowCellValuetopic) method to get the value and is better to use [`GridView.RowCellClick`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellClicktopic) event, because in this event you are sure that double click was performed on cell and nowhere else.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub griddtgpersonal_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles griddtgpersonal.RowCellClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left AndAlso e.Clicks = 2 Then
        DNIValue = griddtgpersonal.GetFocusedRowCellValue("DNI")
        DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    End If
End Sub
```